# Retrieve data from three get resources by clicking fetch button once; angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the data for three get URIs. In the form, the user enters a date which is used to retrieve three different datas from different URIs using the date user has entered. How ever this does not work. Below is my current code that I have written, but it does not work.
In simple words, The user selects a date, which is passed onto the URI and data is retrieved from the API, this happens in three functions, I want all three functions to run when the user clicks fetch.

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center" type="text/ng-template" ng-controller="DailyCtrl" class="users">
          <h1>{{message}}</h1>

<form  style="text-align: center" name="myform" id="myform1" ng-submit="fetch()" >
<input type="date" 
   ng-model="date"  
value="{{ 'date' | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}" />
<div><center><button type="submit" >Fetch</button></center></div>
</form>
{{formdata.date}}
<ul ng-controller="NewCooliosCtrl" ng-repeat="newCoolio in newCoolios.newCoolios">
  <li>{{newCoolio.personID}},  {{newCoolio.placeID}}, {{newCoolio.datePlaced}}</li>
</ul>
 <ul ng-controller="NewPlacesCtrl" ng-repeat="newPlace in newPlaces.newPlaces">
  <li>{{newPlace}} </li>
</ul>
 <ul ng-controller="NewUsersCtrl" ng-repeat="newUser in newUsers.newUsers">
  <li>New Users: {{newUser}} </li>
</ul></br></br>
 </div>
```

Angularjs:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',

function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/getdailydata', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/getnewcoolios.html',
        controller: 'DailyCtrl'
    })
}])
    .controller('DailyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toFetch = [];
    $scope.fetch = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.toFetch.length; i++) {
            $scope.toFetch[i]();
        }
    }
})
    .controller('NewUsersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $scope.fetch = function () {

        var formdata = {
            'date': $filter('date')(this.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
        };

        var inserturl = 'http://94.125.132.253:8001/getnewusers?date=' + formdata.date;

        $http.get(inserturl).success(function (data) {
            console.log(formdata);
            $scope.newUsers = data;
            console.log(inserturl);
            console.log(data);
            $scope.message = 'List of New Users';
        })
    }
    $scope.toFetch.push($scope.fetch);
})
    .controller('NewPlacesCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.fetch = function () {

        var formdata = {
            'date': $filter('date')(this.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
        };

        var inserturl = 'http://94.125.132.253:8001/getnewplaces?date=' + formdata.date;

        $http.get(inserturl).success(function (data) {
            console.log(formdata);
            $scope.newPlaces = data;
            console.log(inserturl);
            console.log(data);
            $scope.message = 'List of New places';
        })
    }
    $scope.toFetch.push($scope.fetch);
})
    .controller('NewCooliosCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.fetch = function () {

        var formdata = {
            'date': $filter('date')(this.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
        };

        var inserturl = 'http://94.125.132.253:8001/getnewcoolios?date=' + formdata.date;

        $http.get(inserturl).success(function (data) {
            console.log(formdata);
            $scope.newCoolios = data;
            console.log(inserturl);
            console.log(data);
            $scope.message = 'List of New Coolios';
        })
    }
    $scope.toFetch.push($scope.fetch);
})
```

Comment: `it does not work` is not a good description of problem. WHat specifically doesn't work? You asked this same question before and unless you provide more details won't likely get much help

Comment: it does not get any data or performs the three functions, there are no errors in the console either. The data from all three controllers should be retrieved but it does not do so.

Comment: from what I see you should create a service to both make the ajax calls and share the data across controllers. Create a demo in plnkr.co

Comment: I have looked into service, but I have three further functions in this controller which work completely fine. So I do not understand how I would fit those three functions in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be in a service really as charlietfl pointed out - but can you not simplify the whole thing down and do something along the lines of (pseudo code!!!) :

```
.controller('DailyCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {

$scope.newCoolios = [];
$scope.newPlaces = [];
$scope.newUsers = [];
$scope.date; 

$scope.fetch = function(){
    var parsedDate = 'date': $filter('date')(this.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

    $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/getnewusers?date=' + parsedData.date).success(function (data) {
        $scope.newUsers = data;
    }); 

    $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/getnewplaces?date=' + parsedData.date).success(function (data) {
        $scope.newPlaces = data;
    }); 

    $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/getnewusers?date=' + parsedData.date).success(function (data) {
        $scope.newUsers = data;
    }); 
}

});
```

The the html could be something like....

```
<div style="text-align: center" type="text/ng-template" ng-controller="DailyCtrl" class="users">
      <h1>{{message}}</h1>
      <input type="date" ng-model="date" value="{{ 'date' | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}" />
      <button ng-click="fetch()">Update</button>
      <ul ng-repeat="newCoolio in newCoolios">
          <li>{{newCoolio.personID}},  {{newCoolio.placeID}}, {{newCoolio.datePlaced}</li>
      </ul>
      <ul ng-repeat="newPlace in newPlaces">
           <li>{{newPlace}} </li>
     </ul>
     <ul ng-repeat="newUser innewUsers">
         <li>New Users: {{newUser}} </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: And will I get the data in the HTML the same way as it is now

Comment: The html would be simpler too - i've update the example.

Comment: Just one thing I had to add which was parsedData.date.